# why extra space under textarea why not in input?

Tags: html, css, input, textarea

**input and textarea both are vertical-align: baseline. but why extra space under textarea why not in input.**

```css
div{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
input,textarea{
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 30px
}
textarea{
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div>
  <textarea type="text" placeholder="message"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with extra space?

Comment: run snippet and check under textarea  space

Comment: You mean the height sry i don't get it?

Comment: there is a space between the red border and the bottom of the textarea.

Comment: run code snippet and see under textarea approx 4px space in chrome browser.

Comment: @J4R you are right

Comment: the baseline for both elements aren't the same

Comment: @TemaniAfif i did not understand .

Comment: The baseline of a textarea is undefined. Chrome and Firefox differ completely on where it's considered to be. It's best not to try to make sense of it. Just follow the advice in the duplicates.